# Is there a term for doing a mitzvah the same way every time?

Tags: words, hebrew, mitzvah

I read in a book (why can't I find it when I want it?) that among the reasons that a tallit gadol has an atarah on it is because there is value in doing a mitzvah the same way each time.  If it did not have it, you could put a tallit on four different ways (eight if it was square).  Is there a Hebrew term for doing a mitzvah consistently the same way?  Could you apply this terminology (if it exists) to other mitzvahs like standing in the same place when davenning (makom kavu'ah)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an interesting question. Are you sure the source you're thinking of was speaking of _mitzvos_ in general and not that particular _mitzva_?

Comment: @WAF From what I remember from several months ago, it was speaking of tallit, but I remember it being phrased generally like "to perform a mitzvah the same way".  My mind went to makom kavu'ah, but I could also think of something like using the same cup for Kiddush or wrapping tfillin with the same pattern.  Obviously the term *minhag* would cover this, but it sounded like it was a specific halakic principle.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45563

Comment: Or building your succah walls the same way. Good find @Fred.

Comment: If memory serves, I think the Aruch Hashulchan says to wear tzitzis the same way each time because of maalin bakodesh v'lo moridin and the front and right are more chashuv than the back and left.

Comment: @loewian Check out Fred's linked answer for more info on that.